# Receiving "Stream encountered HTTP error: 409" when using Twitter API. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, twitterapi-python

```
import tweepy
import time

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
bearer_token = r""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
  def on_tweet(self, tweet):
    try:
      print(tweet.text)
      client.like(tweet.id)
    except Exception as error:
      print(error)
    
    time.sleep(5)

stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)

stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("#Python OR #programming -is:retweet -is:reply"), dry_run=True)

stream.filter()
```

Really unsure what is happening due to me following this youtube video to a T.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tC9GnD0aU2c

Comment: Did you mean to use the `dry_run` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Because you actually don't apply any rules to the stream, you have 2 choices:

- Remove the `dry_run` so the [`add_rules()`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.add_rules) will send the data to Twitter and apply your rule

or

- Add [`stream.sample()`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient.sample) before `filter()`